# Pretty code to check and update a variable

Tags: python

I seem to write this kind of statement a lot:

```
if thishour != datetime.now().hour: 
   thishour = datetime.now().hour
```

It seems like the language should have some sort of shortcut that allows me to not type the function or the variable twice.

I have been reading the Python docs but I don't seem to find any other coding

Comment: If you want it to end up with the same value in either case why not just assign unconditionally?

Comment: Why not just `thishour = datetime.now().hour` ?

Comment: What is the benefit of not assigning a variable its own value if they're the same?

Comment: The above commenters are correct, however, it should be noted that if the assignment is expensive, then simply answering "assign it unconditionally", does not help all situations.

Comment: @VoidTwo Is it even _possible_ for a plain assignment like this to be expensive?  (There are no attribute or key assignments here, so there can't be any hidden calls to `__setattr__` or such.)  Sure, calculating the desired _value_ can be expensive, but that seems inescapable.

Comment: @JohnGordon Generally questions apply an MRE (minimal, reproducible example) and don't always give all the details. This example here would not be expensive, but if a custom object were written with an expensive assignment, then yes I believe it is *possible*.

Answer (score 1):

The usual practice is to store the result of the function call in a variable, then use the variable to compare and assign.

```
restul = datetime.now().hour
if thishour != result: 
   thishour = result
```

This is actually important in general, because if you call this function once in the check and again in the assignment, it might be returning a different result by then.

It is just unusual that someone will check if a variable is not the same prior to assignment (except in some very specific cases, when the assignment has hooks with side effects that might be costly to run).

What I recommend you to do is just assign the new value, like this:

```
thishour = datetime.now().hour
```

Comment: The statement I am asking about would be followed by code that would execute on the hour, as soon as the program notices the hour we were in isn't the same anymore. Adding a variable may make the code shorter, but doesn't make it prettier. I offered some examples of the sort of Python shortcuts I was talking about but someone removed them from my question, not sure why. Didn't help with my question being more understandable obviously. But I am new here so this must be the way.

Comment: If you are doing much more than the assignment, it is a different question. And also, it would matter even less if you could make a check and an assignment at once. Syntax sugar is for common coding patterns, that would make the programmer intent clearer.